# Que algoritmo é esse?

Tags: algoritmo, erlang

Sabendo que: 
`[]` denota um array
`[A|B]` extrai o primeiro elemento do array em `A` e o resto do array em `B` 
`[X, Y] ++ [Z]` cria um array concatenado `[X, Y, Z]`
`[ X || X <- [1, 2, 3, 4], X > 2]` devolve o array `[3, 4]` (leia: crie um `array` com os seguintes valores `[1, 2, 3, 4]` que sejam maiores que 2)

Qual é o nome deste algoritmo?

```
bla([A|B]) -> bla([ X || X <- B, X < A]) ++ [A] ++ bla([ X || X <- B, X >= A]);
bla([]) -> [].
```

Comment: Isso é java mesmo?

Comment: este é um problema relacionado a java, eu não entendi muito bem o que devo responder em "Qual o nome deste algoritmo?" , mas este problema esta mais ligado a logica do que a java

Comment: @diegofm acho que esta faltando o "contexto", a pergunta deve ser parte de uma coisa toda, da forma que esta realmente não tem como responder. Celina se puder confirmar se existe tal contexto poderia ajudar

Comment: Celina existe mais alguma informação a respeito deste exercício, como o contexto ou algo a mais que possa deixar ele mais claro?

Comment: não, não há nenhuma informação, apenas foi passado este contexto.

Comment: talvez a forma que eu tenha escrito esteja um pouco confusa. [ ] denota um array. [A|B] extrai o primeiro elemento do array em A e o resto do array em B. [X, Y] ++ [Z] cria um array concatenado [X, Y, Z]. [ X || X <- [1, 2, 3, 4], X > 2] devolve o array [3, 4]. (leia: crie um array com os valores contidos no array [1, 2, 3, 4] que sejam maiores que 2)

Comment: Isso parece um pseudo-código, teve algum exercício sobre sobre como funciona esse estilo código?

Comment: não, esta questão trata-se de um Desafio, onde contem etapas, essas etapas possuem exercícios de cada gênero, resolvi uma de código html, outra de programação em java e este aqui. Os exercícios são dados sem nenhuma orientação, apenas foi dado o que esta nesta pergunta (Sabendo que [] ...).

Comment: @CelinaShigetomi mas o professor não deu nenhuma orientação em nenhum momento do estilo do pseudo código, tipo || significa uma coisa, <- significa outra coisa e etc?

Comment: então, não tive orientação sobre este exercicio, mas em minha vida academica eu os vejo como operadores (minha visão de acordo com a sintaxe java). || deve ser "or". a<b = a menor que b. ++ ="incremento" e por ai vai (de acordo com a sintaxe java). Mas pode ser que eu esteja vendo as expressões de forma errada.

Comment: eu pensei, pra começar: vamos criar um array com os valores contidos no array [1, 2, 3, 4] que sejam maiores que 2. Então, eu usaria só os valores 3 e 4? E depois colocaria o 3 no array A e o 4 em B?

Comment: Isso tá me parecendo um algoritmo de ordenação. Algo como mergesort ou quicksort.

Comment: Amigo, você resolveu meu problema, eu digitei "quicksort" e ele me direcionou para o proximo desafio. Eu nunca ia adivinhar isso, era apenas um nome. Meus deus! Obrigada

Comment: Palpite certeiro, rs.

Comment: Isso me parece desafio de entrevista de emprego 

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Esse código é Erlang. Coloquei ele funcionando no ideone: http://ideone.com/miMswx - De fato ele faz um quicksort.

Comment: @VictorStafusa um otimo adendo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao que me parece, este algoritmo é o Quick Sort.

Minha implementação em Haskell é bastante parecida com esta sua, embora o enunciado não tenha deixado claro em que linguagem você está trabalhando. Um exemplo de código recursivo (linguagem Haskell):

```
quicksort [] = []
quicksort (x:xs) = quicksort menor ++ (x : quicksort maior)
  where menor = [y | y <- xs, y <= x]
    maior = [y | y <- xs, y > x]
```